# The [graphviz] and [dot] tags should be merged

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphviz) and [dot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dot) appear to be the same thing. Should they be synonymized?

Comment: Are these subset of questions tagged [dot] also about [graphviz]? https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bdot%5d+-%5bgraphviz%5d+-graph+is%3aq&mixed=0

Comment: Besides dot, the Graphviz toolkit also has other algorithms/programs, such as [neato], which has its own tag.